# Two ASP.net buttons on same page problem?

Tags: asp.net

I have two asp buttons on a single page. In the following format
textbox1
required field validator1
button1

textbox2
required filed validator2
button2

if I keep cause validation on both buttons true, then its not firing the server side click event, but I am able to validate these text boxes using required field validators.

If I keep this cause validation on both buttons false, its firing the server side click event, but I am not able to validate these textboxes using required filed validators

Can you please tell me the best solution

Thanks

Comment: Yep, code would be helpful. I've built a multi-button / multi-validator form few days ago and it worked, so it's gotta be something different.

Answer (score 2):

`CausesValidation` should be true on both.

What you need to do is set `ValidationGroup` Button1Validation on the textbox1 validator and button1. Set a `ValidationGroup` of Button2Validation on the textbox2 validator and button2.

Validation groups separate validation rules into groups so that the groups don't overlap and interfere with each other.

Comment: I tried with validation groups also no change in the result. Here I am sending two seperate buttons please check out these two following comments

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of the RequiredFieldValidator is that when you don't insert something into the textbox to which it's coupled, and client side validation is turned on (defaults to true), then it won't posback and as such the server side event never gets hit.

You can turn off the client side validation on the validator control by setting the property [EnableClientScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.enableclientscript.aspx) to false:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="TextBoxRequiredValidator" 
    ControlToValidate="NumberTextBox"
    EnableClientScript="False"
    Display="Dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a value."
    Text="*"
    runat="server"/>
```

Taken from the MSDN documentation.

Comment: Won't turning off client validation just cause both validators to fire server side and cause Page.IsValid to be false. I think what he wants is to separate the two groups of textbox buttons so that validation only fires on the single button textbox pair.

Comment: @sathish turning off client validation is not the solution. Are you testing for Page.IsValid on your server side click event. I think you'll find it will be false.

Comment: @madcapnmckay,  Yes you are correct. It's always returning false. What is the correct solution for this, I have been searching for this from past two days. Please help me if you have any solution.

Comment: @sathish If you post your markup and event handlers I'll see what I can do.